# Telegram channel posts doesn't open in cefsharp web browser

Tags: vb.net, telegram, cefsharp

I used a cef web browser in vb.NET. This is my code:

```
browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser(x)
Me.Controls.Add(browser)
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

When `x="http://www.google.com"` everything is fine and Google was loaded successfully, and probably it is fine in other sites as well.

But when `x="https://t.me/khazareeee/2"` for loading a telegram channel post, my web browser doesn't work!

It appears that screen will load like a blank page for very short period of time on this site.

Comment: Check the log file https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file  Also http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_LoadError.htm will be called if there is an error while loading. Does your url load in chrome?

Comment: My url was loaded in chrome

Comment: What version of Chrome? What version of CefSharp are you using? It's entirely possible that CEF doesn't support a feature that telegram requires. Never used it myself so know nothing about it. You'll have to debug this yourself.

Comment: My system in x64 and cefsharp3

Comment: Infact cefsharp open telegram web for very shortley time but after this, redirect to blank page. I can see telegram web page blue style for very shortly time, but a few time later screen will white!

Comment: Opening Devtools might be useful see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Answer (score 1):

It seems that chrome has banned telegram links in India. That's why it doesn't work. I'm using kali linux and I tried to access the link from chrome it doesn't work. But later I tried to access it with firefox and it worked. So my suggestion would be change the browser